# Panel is not scrollable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, panel

Please guide how to add scrolling event to this panel

```
            this.pnlContainer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.pnlContainer.Name = "pnlContainer";
            this.pnlContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1249, 799);
            this.pnlContainer.AutoScroll = false;
            this.pnlContainer.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
            this.pnlContainer.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
            this.pnlContainer.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: `this.pnlContainer.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.pnlContainer_Scroll);`

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Can you please help me to write the scoll event code as I am not able to fix that

Answer (score 1):

First, you must define the event hanlder

```
private void pnlContainer_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Then you should subscribe this handler to scroll event of your control.

```
this.pnlContainer.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.pnlContainer_Scroll);
```